# Why do these different echo commands all print the same thing despite different types of quoting?

Tags: bash, shell

```
S=2

echo $S
echo "$S"
bash -c " echo $S "
bash -c " echo '$S' "
bash -c " echo "$S" "
```

Why do all of these echo the same thing? They all print `2` and I don't understand why.

The most confusing one for me is `bash -c " echo '$S' "`, since `echo '$S'` = `$S`. How come `bash -c " echo '$S' "` works like the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> bash -c " echo '$S' "
> ```

Because the string `" echo '$S' "` is double quoted it is being **interpolated by the outer shell**. The single quotes aren't relevant at this stage. The outer shell expands `$S` and the resulting command is:

```
bash -c " echo '2' "
```

Then the inner `bash` command runs and, as you can see, the string being echoed is the fixed string `'2'` with no variable.

> ```
> bash -c " echo "$S" "
> ```

This looks like it contains quotes inside of quotes, but looks can be deceiving. What you actually have is `" echo "` adjacent to `$S` adjacent to `" "`.

The result is still `2`, but I just wanted to point out that this isn't analogous to the `bash -c " echo '$S' "` case above, which *does* have nested quotes.

#### Follow up case

```
bash -c ' echo "$S" '
```

You didn't write this form where the outer quotes are single quotes. If you had, you might be puzzled that it *doesn't* print `2` like the rest. That's weird. Why not?

Answer: Unlike all the versions you posted, this one has the *inner shell* doing the expansion of `$S`. The command is single quoted which prevents the outer shell from expanding it, so `$S` makes it intact to the inner shell. The inner shell, though, doesn't have a variable called `$S`, and ends up just printing a blank line.

Why doesn't it have `S=2`? It's because `S` was not [exported](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-variables-export). In order for a variable to be visible in a child process it needs to be exported with

```
export S=2
```

or

```
S=2
export S
```

Unexported variables are only visible in the current process and are unset in child processes.

Comment: I just found ```bash -c ' echo '$S' '``` = 2 as the other double quotes, it got me more confused

Comment: `bash -c ' echo '$S' '` is exactly the same as `bash -c " echo "$S" "`. It jumps in and out of quotes. The `$S` isn't double quoted, it's *not quoted at all*.